# Database migration from Postgres to Mysql

Tags: 7, database

We have a website in Drupal 7 running on Postgres database. We are planning to upgrade to Drupal 8 very soon, but we want to first migrate the database from Postgres to Mysql.

I was just wondering if anyone has done this before and has any thoughts about how to do this? I see some options in Mysql Workbench but haven't tried it yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would give this a shot. I have used this to do MSSQL->MySQL before. https://dbconvert.com/postgresql/mysql/

Comment: thanks @Kevin will give it a shot